# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una extensión de chrome mi macro que hice en dejaclick?

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy realizando una macro en un grabador llamado dejaclick para poder logearme, seleccionar menus y llenar formularios en el portal interno de mi empresa pero solo cuentan con Chromebooks entonces se me ocurrió hacerlo en una extensión para al ejecutarla me haga todo en automático, me podrán ayudar a saber cómo hacerlo y darme idea si puedo hacerla en algún lenguaje que acepte la Chromebook?